# Extend a Typescript generic with additional data

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a helper utility for Firestore collection data using Typescript. The utility should be unaware of what data is coming in but express the correct return type to whatever calls it. I'm unsure how to pass my Typescript types to the function and have it return properly. So far what I have is as follows:

```js
interface CollectionWithId<T extends {}> {
  id: string;
}

/**
 * Get all docs from collection `collectionName` optionally
 * @param collectionName
 */
export async function getCollectionDocs<T>(collectionName: string): Promise<CollectionWithId<T>[]> {
  const documentQuery = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionName);
  const documentQuerySnapshot = await documentQuery.get();

  return documentQuerySnapshot.empty
    ? []
    : _map(documentQuerySnapshot.docs, (doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }));
}
```

Upon calling `getCollectionDocs<User>()`, I'd expect the returned data to autocomplete all properties of a User. Right now, I only get the `id` property.

[image]

How can I get all properties of my `User` interface after Firestore has done its thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using information found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225#issuecomment-736008713), I did the following:

```js
type CollectionWithId<T> = T & {
  id: string;
};

export async function getCollectionDocs<T>(
  collectionName: string,
  limit?: number,
  offset?: number
): Promise<CollectionWithId<T>[]> {
  ...
}
```

This seems to work as expected.

[image]